# Using lmax Disruptor (3.0) in java to process millions of documents

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I have the following use-case:

When my service starts, it may need to deal with millions of documents in as short of a burst as possible. There will be three sources of data.

I have set up the following:

```
    /* batchSize = 100, bufferSize = 2^30
    public MyDisruptor(@NonNull final MyDisruptorConfig config) {
        batchSize = config.getBatchSize();
        bufferSize = config.getBufferSize();
        this.eventHandler = config.getEventHandler();
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = createThreadFactory("disruptor-threads-%d");
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(threadFactory);
        ringBuffer = RingBuffer.createMultiProducer(new EventFactory(), bufferSize, new YieldingWaitStrategy());
        sequenceBarrier = ringBuffer.newBarrier();
        batchEventProcessor = new BatchEventProcessor<>(ringBuffer, sequenceBarrier, eventHandler);
        ringBuffer.addGatingSequences(batchEventProcessor.getSequence());
        executorService.submit(batchEventProcessor);
    }

    public void consume(@NonNull final List<Document> documents) {
        List<List<Document>> subLists = Lists.partition(documents, batchSize);
        for (List<Document> subList : subLists) {
            log.info("publishing sublist of size {}", subList.size());
            long high = ringBuffer.next(subList.size());
            long low = high - (subList.size() - 1);
            long position = low;
            for (Document document: subList) {
                ringBuffer.get(position++).setEvent(document);
            }
            ringBuffer.publish(low, high);
            lastPublishedSequence.set(high);
        }
    }
```

Each of my sources calls consume, I use Guice to create a Singleton disruptor.

My eventHandler routine is

```
    public void onEvent(Event event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
        Document document = event.getValue();
        handler.processDocument(document); //send the document to handler
        if (endOfBatch) {
            handler.processDocumentsList(); // tell handler to process all documents so far.
        }
    }
```

I am seeing in my logs that the producer (`consume`) is stalling at times. I assume that this is when the ringBuffer is full, and the eventHandler is not able to process quickly enough. I see that the eventHandler is processing documents (from my logs) and then after a while the producer starts publishing more documents to the ring buffer.

Questions:

- Am I using the correct Disruptor pattern? I see there are quite a few ways to use it. I chose to use the batchEventProcessor so it would signal `endOfBatch`.
- How can I increase the efficiency of my EventHandler? processDocumentsList can be slow.
- Should I use parallel EventHandlers? The lmax [user-guide](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/user-guide/index.html#_design_and_implementation) mentions that this is possible, and the [FAQ](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-you-arrange-a-disruptor-with-multiple-consumers-so-that-each-event-is-only-consumed-once) has a question on it. But how do I use this with the batchEventProcessor? It only takes one eventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `handler` stateful?  If not, you can use multiple parallel event handlers to process the documents.  You could implement a basic sharding strategy where only one of the handlers processes each event.

`endOfBatch` is usually used to speed up the speed of processing by optimising IO operations that benefit from batching.  E.g. writing to file on each event but only flushing on `endOfBatch`.

It's hard to give any more advice without know what happens in your document processor.